How to order by totals in a combined stacked bar and scatter plot in R using ggplot
How can I sort Fuel in this chart by value_out.net i.e. the net values marked as black dots?
Please see the figure, and the code below:

fuels_out_plot_w_tot_order <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = all_fuels, aes(x = Fuel, y = value_out, fill = stage_emission), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(data = all_fuels, aes(x = Fuel, y = value_out.net), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous("g CO2e/kWh", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / conv_mj_kwh, name = "g CO2e/MJ")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Well-to-wheel emissions (powertrain efficiency considered)") +
  coord_flip(); fuels_out_plot_w_tot_order

I played around with reorder() but I couldn't get it to work.

Please make this question reproducible by including the data necessary to run the code. You can paste the output from running dput(all_fuels).

all_fuels <- all_fuels %>%
mutate(Fuel = forcats::fct_reorder(Fuel, value_out.net))
